# How to change systemUIVisibility on SdkVersion 30

Tags: android, android-fullscreen, android-11

Recently Google has deprecated setting system UI visibility directly using the `setSystemUIVisibility` method found in the View class and passing flags to it.

[image: Deprecated setSystemUiVisibility method]

I couldn't find the source code for this as it's not released publically yet. Do you guys know how I can achieve going fullscreen without using this method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes now since it is deprecated, you can use:

```
window.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(false)
```

Then make sure you make the status bar transparent as well by adding below style to your app theme

```
<item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

Hope this helps :)