# setSystemUiVisibility and View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR DEPRECATED no Example found in Stack or Google

Tags: android, statusbar, deprecated, flags, window-decoration

`setSystemUiVisibility` and `View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR` are deprecated.

What's the equivalent to this:

```
View decor = getWindow().getDecorView();

decor.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR);
```

And this:

```
decor.setSystemUiVisibility(0);
```

I have tried `APPEARANCE_LIGHT_NAVIGATION_BARS` and `WindowInsetsController` but I don't know how to put it together.

The closest example I came across is this:

[StackOverflow example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62643517/immersive-fullscreen-on-android-11)

Comment: Duplicate of [android.view.View.systemUiVisibility deprecated. What is the replacement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62577645/android-view-view-systemuivisibility-deprecated-what-is-the-replacement) and [How to change systemUIVisibility on SdkVersion 30](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62624644/how-to-change-systemuivisibility-on-sdkversion-30?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: I already see that post, it did not help at all and it is in kotlin not java

Comment: I agree, I don't think this is a duplicate.  Related, but not duplicate.

Comment: Agreed with my fellow programmers above... This is a Java post and the linked answers are strictly Kotlin... So many try-hards out there with an itchy dupe question trigger finger... Hope the rep points were worth it man.

Comment: Maybe this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65423778/system-ui-flag-light-status-bar-and-flag-translucent-status-is-deprecated/66089566#66089566