# SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR and FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS is deprecated

Tags: android, kotlin

This code is deprecated in API 30. Any idea how to update this?

```
private fun setSystemBarLight(act: Activity) {
      if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
           val view: View = act.findViewById(android.R.id.content)
           var flags: Int = view.systemUiVisibility
           flags = flags or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR
           view.systemUiVisibility = flags
      }
}
```

**FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS** is also deprecated here. I need help fixing this warning.

```
    private fun setSystemBarColor(act: Activity, color: String?) {
                val window: Window = act.window
                window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS)
                window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS)
                window.statusBarColor = Color.parseColor(color)
            }
```

Comment: I am also looking for same solution @Web Services, do you have any updated solution?

Answer (score 25):

***These solutions only work on API >= 23.***

### UPDATE:

As suggested in the comment section, you can use **[WindowInsetsControllerCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/view/WindowInsetsControllerCompat#setAppearanceLightStatusBars(boolean))** as follows.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    Window window = getWindow();
    View decorView = window.getDecorView();

    WindowInsetsControllerCompat wic = new WindowInsetsControllerCompat(window, decorView);

    wic.setAppearanceLightStatusBars(true); // true or false as desired.

    // And then you can set any background color to the status bar.
    window.setStatusBarColor(Color.WHITE);
}
```

**OLD ANSWER:**

In API level 30 **[setSystemUiVisibility()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR)** has been deprecated. Hence you should use **[WindowInsetsController](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowInsetsController#setSystemBarsAppearance(int,%20int))**. The below code will make the status bar light, that means the text in the statut bar will be black.

```
Window window = getWindow();
View decorView = window.getDecorView();

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
    WindowInsetsController wic = decorView.getWindowInsetsController();
    wic.setSystemBarsAppearance(APPEARANCE_LIGHT_STATUS_BARS, APPEARANCE_LIGHT_STATUS_BARS);
} else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR);
}

// set any light background color to the status bar. e.g. - white or light blue
window.setStatusBarColor(Color.WHITE);
```

to clear this, use

```
wic.setSystemBarsAppearance(0, APPEARANCE_LIGHT_STATUS_BARS);
```

Comment: Now this answer is outdated as well, as one should use `WindowInsetsControllerCompat(window, window.decorView)` and `wic.isAppearanceLightStatusBars`.

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin solution to change status bar fonts color to dark

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        val window: Window = window
        val decorView: View = window.decorView
        val wic = WindowInsetsControllerCompat(window, decorView)
        wic.isAppearanceLightStatusBars = true // true or false as desired.

        // And then you can set any background color to the status bar.
        window.statusBarColor = Color.WHITE
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes now since it is deprecated, you can use:

```
window.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(false)
```

Then make sure you make the status bar transparent as well by adding below style to your app theme

```
<item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

Comment: This works only in API level 30 and higher

Answer (score 0):

```
    WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
    val wic = WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window, window.decorView)
    wic?.systemBarsBehavior = WindowInsetsControllerCompat.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_BARS_BY_SWIPE
    wic?.isAppearanceLightStatusBars = true
    window.statusBarColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
```

Comment: Please explain your solution. Answers which do not have an explanation and are only code get flagged as low effort.

Comment: in androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0  you can use this

Answer (score 0):

You can use an extension like below, it's basically uses compatible methods.

```
fun Activity.setStatusBarColorDirectly(@ColorInt color: Int) {
   window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS)
   window.statusBarColor = color
   val windowInsetsController = WindowInsetsControllerCompat(window, window.decorView)
   windowInsetsController.isAppearanceLightStatusBars = true
}
```