# White Status Bar in dark mode

Tags: android, statusbar

Is it possible to make white status bar programmatically in dark mode? (*Application is based on single Activity, and I have to make this only for one fragment*)

also app should based on `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar` to have no bad effect on other styles.

I've tried to set white color and ui visibility to light mode, but it seems force dark is applied to status bar background automatically.

the code looks like this:

```
var flags = it.decorView.systemUiVisibility or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR
window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = flags

                     //it is #F0F0F0 in white and night sources 
var statusBarColor = context.getColorCompat(R.color.white) 
window?.statusBarColor = statusBarColor
```

but only systemUiVisibility flag applies:

[image]

Comment: check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74273585/15749574

Comment: @JustSightseeing thank you. while trying this suggestion I found a solution for my case https://stackoverflow.com/a/75237717/5599807

Comment: No worries, don't forget to mark your answer as the solution (I think you have to wait for a day before doing that)

Comment: if my answer helps you please upvote to help others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, answer was in the question... but I haven't think to try to disable force dark before...

as I've mentioned as `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar` been used I have to disable forceDark.

so the solution in this case looks like:

```
    val decorView = window.decorView
    val wic = WindowInsetsControllerCompat(window, decorView)
    wic.isAppearanceLightStatusBars = true

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {

        //disable force dark for Light theme
        window.decorView.isForceDarkAllowed = false
    }
    window.statusBarColor = Color.WHITE
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to Util file

```js
private val insetsController: WindowInsetsControllerCompat? by lazy {
  activity?.window?.decorView?.let(ViewCompat::getWindowInsetsController)
}

private fun setLightStatusBar(light: Boolean) {
    insetsController?.isAppearanceLightStatusBars = light
}
```

Hope it will solve your issue.

Comment: thank you, for an answer. but it is not my case: I use only native (kotlin)

Comment: isn't `view.setSystemUiVisibility(flags)` depreciated?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    Window window = getWindow();
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
    window.setStatusBarColor(Color.BLUE);
}
```

and an other way is to create 2 themes class and define specific color for status bar.